# Share Multiplayer World

Tags: terraria

A buddy and I have been playing Terraria together in a joint world. I hosted and so I have the world and can play in single player when he's not around.  He'd like to do the same, is this possible?

I doubt we could both play it and then have it sync up the changes, but is there a way to send him the world file and then when we go to play together copy it back or something along those lines?

Comment: Please provide more details as to what exactly you are doing.  Are you currently using the Host & Play option?

Comment: Guess I should have been more specific about my requirements since there are multiple solutions. Thank you everyone for your answers and feedback.  I will post my exact solution above which uses a combination of these answers. However, I found the suggestion by OrigamiRobot to use a Dedicated Server the most helpful for my situation which is why I have chosen it as the accepted answer, wish I could do more than just +1 for the rest of you. Thanks again!

Comment: Hah, we also use DynDNS but I completely took that for granted.  Nice job.  Good call on DropBox for your players folder.  Enjoy playing Terraria unrestricted by your location!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TerrariaServer.exe** is located in your Steam Terraria folder.  If you run that on your computer, he can connect to the world whenever your computer is on.

[This link](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Setting_up_a_Terraria_server#Setting_up_dedicated_server_without_configuration_file) can help set this up.

Comment: The dedicated server is also included with the game distribution. As the asker plays himself, he will have that. Also, the questions point was: What to do when the asker is not there. So I don’t think a (ded.) server is an option.

Comment: If you run the dedicated server, no one has to be there.  When the asker is not there, the server is still running.  It is exactly what he wants.  What comes with the game is the "Host & Play" option which is different than a dedicated server.

Comment: Kissaki, as @OrigamiRobot said, the latest version the game only has a "Host and Play" option.  For either person to play alone at any time, running a dedicated continuously seems like the best option.

Comment: Read the question again. He was running the host himself and he can't get dedicated hosting...

Comment: You can run the dedicated server on your own machine.  I'm not talking about dedicated hosting.

Comment: @Tom, read http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Server_Console - there is a console application you can download from the Terraria website.  It works exactly the same as the play and host; you've got your world and your port.  It runs continuously, whether or not there are players connected.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot: The OP is asking "to let his friend play in single player if he is not around", I don't see how he can do that when his computer is off. If it's as simple as leaving the computer running with either version then the OP wouldn't have asked this question...

Comment: @Ian: I'm quite aware of that as I'm running tMod myself; this is not an answer to the OPs problem. And as you state it works **exactly the same** and runs continuously whether or not there are players connected...

Comment: @Tom - now you are assuming that his computer is off.  "When he is not around" could simply mean that he is not logged in to Terraria.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot: It's not an assumption, it's a fact. If his computer is off the other person will be unable to play, it's as simple as that. You are the one making the assumption here by assuming whether or not he would be logged in to Terraria, which only makes your arguing more subjective...

Comment: Uh … You mean the ded I have in my folder is the one I downloaded? I thought I downloaded an noticed there was one distributed with the game anyway. If there really is no `TerrariaServer.exe` distributed with the game, then my fault on that part.

Comment: @Ian: For a dedicated server to run you still need a running computer. And that’s what I’m getting at. If he is not there to host a normal game, then he will probably not want to keep the PC running just for that. Anyway, the question was on playing and merging the same world.

Comment: @Kissaki - Yes, if he wants to turn his machine off and still let his friend have access to the world, then something like dropbox is definitely the better solution.  Personally, I leave my machine on all the time anyway and so does my friend who runs the Terraria Server software for our world.  So that is the better solution for us.  I have been trying to explain that there are different solutions based on the OP's situation but it seems to have gotten out of hand.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR: Simply use** [**Dropbox**](http://www.dropbox.com/), or get your hands dirty with batch files and [Boar](http://code.google.com/p/boar/).

---

This would be called batch automation.

Simply, you would create a batch file that

1. Downloads the changes.
2. Hosts your server or starts your Terraria client.
3. Upload the changes when you are done.

I wouldn't suggest uploading the whole map as that could be around 100 MB, while I belief that when playing only a small part of the 100 MB is really affected. What you need is a binary version control system, try looking into [Boar](http://code.google.com/p/boar/) or come up with something like [RDiff-Backup](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/) which might be easier to automate over the command line.

It would look something like this:

```
line that tells your BVCS to download changes

%ProgramFiles%\Terraria\Terraria.exe

line that tells your BVCS to upload changes
```

The batch will automatically pause till Terraria is closed.

Good luck! :)

PS: You could commit a `.lock` file and check for it to ensure you don't play simultaneously...

---

Alternatively, you could try to use [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/) and skip the version control system altogether.

> I'd do it via dropbox , share the folder, and then hardlink to where you need it to be, that way DB only syncs actual changes to the file as well
>
> — [Mokubai's suggestion on the Super User chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1133126#1133126).

Ben Blank explained in the comments that this is completely automatable. :)

Comment: Dropbox wouldn't need additional automation for this.  A friend of mine and I use it to share a Minecraft world in much the same way.  Move the save folder into your drop box, hardlink it back to where Terraria expects it ([yes, you can do this even in Windows](http://wiki.dropbox.com/TipsAndTricks/SyncOtherFolders#Windows.28NeedsNTFSfilesystem.29)), share the folder, and have your friend hardlink it as well.  You have to make sure not to both play it offline at the same time and to let Dropbox sync before playing, but it works extremely well.

Comment: Hmm, if it's an update-on-changes mechanism then it would indeed work well. Thanks for enlightening us... :)

Comment: All of this is nice, but it is unnecessary.  The Terraria dedicated server was created for this exact purpose.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot: Not really, because the OP can't host the Terraria server.

Comment: @Tom - The OP is using the "Host & Play" option that is in the Terraria client.  This requires that he be in the game in order for anyone else to connect.  He wants his friend to be able to connect when he is not.  The dedicated server software allows the server to be running at all times even when there are no players.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot: **He did not mention that**, it doesn't even matter as you could as well run the GUI version on a dedicated server **which he doesn't seem to have**. Given his profile, he wouldn't ask for a sharing solution instead of a hosting solution...

Comment: You don't have to have dedicated server HARDWARE to run the Terraria dedicated server SOFTWARE.  As as have said, the GUI version (Host & Play) requires that he be logged in to Terraria.  This is the problem.  He does not want to be logged in in order for his friend to play.  He also did not mention anything about "offline" in the original question.  You changed it to say that.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot: **He did not mention that**, stop imagining because it's not constructive. As he stopped hosting it, the world is now offline so I didn't change a thing other than clarifying the question title...

Comment: @Tom - This argument could be solved by the OP coming in and providing more details.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot: What argument? This is irrelevant to my answer...

Comment: @OrigamiRobot: What details? Everything is provided...

Answer (score 3):

Simple. Just copy and manage your world file. It is saved in the `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Terraria\Worlds` folder. (Enter that path in your explorers location path.)

You can simply copy the world file to your friends computer in the same folder and run it.

Make sure you don’t overwrite what you actually want to use. Maybe back them up in a separate folder whenever you will overwrite or something. (Personally, I’m using git version control to make sure I don’t lose anything – but that’s probably for the more tech-savy/devs/coders.)

Comment: This would soak up quite some bandwidth; Git VCS also isn't not meant to store binaries as that will take up quite some space in your repository, pushing and pulling  again soaks up a lot of bandwidth as binary diff isn't used afaik...

Comment: The Git part was just an info on what I used locally. Git is not easy to use for first-timers. Even if it’s not diffing, with compression it can be a valid option.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use a sync service where you can share folders, like [wuala](http://wuala.com), [ubuntu one](http://one.ubuntu.com) or [dropbox](http://dropbox.com), if you don’t use one yet (they are useful way beyond that).

Then install the [link shell extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html). This one is a program where you can install so-called symlinks and juntions. You don’t have to know what that is, but “simply” to create a symlink. You do this by

1. Moving your `world5.wld` to a folder inside the sync folder, e.g. `C:\Users\<Your Username>\Dropbox\Terraria shared`
2. Share this folder with your friend, which has to do everything like you, except moving the file and creating the folder (it will appear on his computer once shared) Sharing should be easy, with dropbox, it’s in the context menu, too, I think.
3. Pick the moved World file as link source as shown [here](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html#usinglinkshellextension).
4. Go back to your save folder, right click it and select `Drop as → Symbolic Link` (shown above, too, but you’ll want to pick “Symbolic” instead of “Hard” Link)

If the context menu entries aren’t shown directly after installing link shell extension, you’ll have to reboot.

I hope everything is clear.

PS: Why to do all this? in order to share this file and at the same time keep a link to it that terraria can follow to find it. Simple windows shortcuts don’t suffice here, thus the symlink.

Comment: +1 Been using this extension for a long time and it's a handier way than over the console.

Comment: I wish everyone would use linux. It’d be so much easier. On linux, there are only symlinks and no stupid “shortcuts”, and you create them by holding shift while dropping a dragged file. (Additionally, on KDE, after each file drop, a small context menu asks you if you want to move the file, or create a link)

Comment: @flying: On Linux, there are hard and soft symlinks, not just symlinks. On Windows, shortcuts allow you to provide more options about how the process should start; on Linux these are also existing under the form of launchers. How you create is just a GUI action and is easy to manipulate. For me, both operating systems work kind of equal in the aspect of linking to files and directories, they are just coined different terms...

Comment: but on linux you usually use symlinks and the creation and information of/about them is available in every gui, other than on windows, where you have to use a 3rd-party tool.

Comment: @flyingsheep: Because they are not meant to be seen and you do have properties on shortcuts. And also; Gnome, KDE and Xfce are third-party written GUIs written on top of the X11 display system... ;)

Comment: i don’t understand your first sentence, and your comparison is flawed: in open-source-products, there is no such thing as 3rd party, since the first dozen parties are dead, and the ten thousand others have made everything apart from the first ideas and concepts. but we really should discuss this elsewhere :)

Comment: @flyingsheep: It's third party in the sense that if I install Gentoo; then installing Gnome, KDE or Xfce on top of that is something that I install from another party than the Gentoo party. I don't think we should be discussing this in the first place... :)

Answer (score 1):

*Solution: provided by [theChrisKent](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/9314/thechriskent), taken from the question:*

I have used a combination of the answers below to make this game even more awesome. First I setup a **Dedicated server** as mentioned by [OrigamiRobot](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24375/how-do-i-play-on-an-offline-world-with-a-friend-in-turns/24378#24378). This was super simple and meets my requirements perfectly. I don't mind leaving my computer on all the time with this running. To do this I also had to do a couple of other things unique to my situation:

- Setup a static route in my router for port 7777 to the machine where I am running the dedicated server
- Registered with [DynDNS.org](http://www.dyndns.org) to get a domain name to be used with my dynamic IP Address
- I setup the DynDNS account in my router and I was good to go (This is needed so that my friend can ping the domain name and get my current ip address should it change in the future).

Doing that took care of my need to share the world file without us having to sync it between run times.

Looking at the other answers, [Kissaki](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24375/how-do-i-play-on-an-offline-world-with-a-friend-in-turns/24394#24394) provided me with the folders I needed, and I used [flying sheep](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24375/how-do-i-play-on-an-offline-world-with-a-friend-in-turns/24426#24426)'s answer about
**symlinks** along with [Tom Wijsman](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24375/how-do-i-play-on-an-offline-world-with-a-friend)'s suggestion of using **DropBox** to share my player folder. I use the dedicated server to hold onto the world, but putting my player folder in dropbox allows me to play as the same character regardless of which of my machines I am using.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a flash drive, so when you give it to him he edits the world and then he gives the flash drive back and you put edit it and so on.